# Sublime Text Python builds and opening a terminal takes very long time

Tags: python, macos, terminal, sublimetext

I have been learning a lot of python recently using sublime text on a mac, I installed python 3 and have mainly been using that but as a lot of documentation is in python 2.7 and it comes with the Mac I decided to start using 2.7 instead. I have quite a few libraries installed (for python 3 and for 2.7) When I load my terminal it takes a good 15 seconds for it to get to the prompt and it takes the same amount of time to build python 2.7 from sublime text before it starts executing the code.

I know this post is probably too vague but if anyone has had a similar experience or could suggest anything to point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `python -vvv` to dump out imports Python is doing when it starts up. If the slowdown is by a third party library this should give a hint.

Check your `~/.bashrc` script for duplicate entries (see comments below).

Comment: What is strange is that if I run Python from terminal when it eventually loads Python runs / builds instantly. But when I load the actual terminal itself it takes forever, and building from sublime text does the same. So I am guessing its nothing to do with the libraries, but something that terminal loads (and somehow sublime) upon execution?

Comment: Smells like your user shell startup scripts do something on the "login" or terminal open operation which takes the time.

Comment: Can you check your `~/.bashrc` file or are you familiar with UNIX shell and how it starts up?

Comment: Unfortunately not only switched from Windows a few months back and really haven't got into any of the inner workings of UNIX

Comment: The terminal command prompt is "shell" and by default OSX runs shell called Bash. Bash runs a certain scripts every time you start up a terminal. It sounds like some (package/application) you have installed has modified this script and contains something which slows down the bash startup.

Comment: Here you can find information how to peek into Bash start scripts http://superuser.com/a/147699/60103

Comment: Thanks a lot worked perfectly , turns out (No idea how) once I opened up my bash script from terminal:

source ~/.bash_profile

I found I had literally hundreds of duplicate entries with:

export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"

Once I left just one and removed all others, saved it. Works instantly again. I am not sure how to change the answer on here to your second to last answer.